# Issue finding keyAlias 'upload' when building appbundle from VS Code (flutter)

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, android-keystore

I'm signing a keystore to upload a flutter app to google play for the first time, and having trouble finding a keystore. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Specifically, I'm getting the following error:

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/charl/Documents/Development/flutter_apps/twitter_drafts/android/app/build.gradle' line: 64
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method keyAlias() for arguments [upload] on BuildType$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=true, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[/Users/charl/Documents/Development/flutter_apps/twitter_drafts/build/app/intermediates/default_proguard_files/global/proguard-android.txt-7.3.0, /Users/charl/Documents/Development/SDKs/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter_proguard_rules.pro, /Users/charl/Documents/Development/flutter_apps/twitter_drafts/android/app/proguard-rules.pro], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType$AgpDecorated.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

## Here is my Build Gradle file:
Build Gradle File

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.pagefamdesigns.application_name"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pagefamdesigns.application_name"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }
}
```

And here's my Key.properties file:

```
storePassword=[[password is here]]
keyPassword=[[password is here]]
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=/Users/charl/upload-keystore.jks
```

(There is a file at that location)

[image: Screenshot of my File Structure]

Comment: May be you misspelled the alias

Comment: Did you see that somewhere in the provided files? I'm not seeing any misspellings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was that I had copied the keystore settings into the `buildTypes` section within the `android` section of the build.gradle file. I was supposed to have something else in the `buildTypes` section, and include the keystore stuff in the `signingConfigs` section.

## Bad

```
android {

... Some stuff

    buildTypes {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
}
```

## Good

```
android {

... Some stuff

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}
```